# UIImage from NSData in UITableView - performance issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimage, nsdata

I am storing images from Photos Album in my app documents directory as NSData and than displaying them in UITableView. I have problem with performance. It takes a good few seconds to save image into app directory and I have same problem when than loading them into TableView. This is my code to store images:

```
//Convert UIImage to NSData
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)];

//Save image to app documents directory
NSError *error;
[imageData writeToFile:fullImagePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&error];
```

That is how I load them into UITableView:

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

cell.imageView.image = myImage;
```

What may cause these performance issues? Is it any other way to store and retrieve images from app documents directory?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two approaches:

First you might consider scaling down the images before you save them, or save an additional smaller copy for display in the table view. It depends how good images you need - presumably for the table view not as large as full scale pictures with MB of data. Actually, the images will also look better if they are properly scaled. This by itself should take care of the delays.

Second, you might consider loading the images asynchronously. Maintain a mutable array of images to be downloaded. Create a singleton that does the download and notifies the table view when finished. Set `cell.imageView.image` in the notification (or delegate) callback.

Comment: Thanks, I will try scaling and asynchronously loading.